# How do i avoid eval() from converting 1e-1 to 0.1?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using a thrid party javascript library that uses `eval()` so when i call one of it's functions with the `"1e-1"` value as a parameter i get `0.1` returned. How can i escape this or avoid it from parsing the number?

A basic example would be:

```
console.log(eval("1e-1"));
```

I want the result to be 1e-1, but eval still needs to be there.

---

**EDIT:**

Okay Ignore the console example above
**[THIS is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/vLpt6/42/)** it should work on:

There is no way around using this library. Sorry.

Comment: Reject Javascript frameworks which make excessive use of `eval`. eval = evil.

Comment: If I've understood what you want correctly, can you wrap the `1e-1` in quotes? Then it would be treated as a string literal: `eval("'1e-1'");`

Comment: I tried that. I tried character codes, i tried special characters, appending `&nbsp;`. I tried all the obvious things.

Comment: @capdragon - The quotes should definitely work. The string you pass to `eval` contains a string literal. It won't do anything special with it.

Comment: @capdragon - No problem :) Bergi seems to have posted the same thing as an answer, so I guess he can get the credit!

Comment: I've updated my original question with an example of the library and where it should work.

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to do this is to simply replace the hyphen with it's Character Entity code instead:

```
console.log(eval("1e&#45;1"));
```

**Update**

After experimenting for quite a while, the only thing that was close is placing spaces before and after the hyphen:

```
features[1].attributes.tag= "1e - 1";
```

I thought it worth mentioning incase this will suffice for what you need.

Comment: What does the function do that you're passing this to? Why are you passing this value to the function atall if you don't want it to use the value correctly? A bit more information will be very helpful.

Comment: I've not had much luck either but i've updated with a possible solution for you. I hope this helps and I'll come back if I discover something more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use eval(). Of course, `Number("1e-1")` has the same "problem". However, if you want a string back from eval you have to feed it with one: `eval("'1e-1'")`.

Comment: I agree, though the OP states a library is using it, so it's likely out of the poster's control.

Comment: So then, as Jamiec said above, don't use that library :-)

Comment: As the old saying goes: if the wheel's square, reinvent it!